# -webkit-box-orient is lost when compile from less to css

Tags: css

I have tried this, but it's not working. Any ideas?

```
      /* autoprefixer: off */
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      /* autoprefixer: on */
```

My intension is to restrict the content of text to three lines and add the '...' effect at the end.

Comment: I recommend you use `flexbox`. `box-orient` is non-standard!

Comment: change to use `flexbox`

Comment: can you specify how?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `!`. Only that worked for me

```
/*! autoprefixer: off */
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
/*! autoprefixer: on */
```